# ASP Cookies or Session to store background colour

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, asp-classic

I've got some javascript which changes the background colour on mouse click:

```
<input type="button" name="colr" value=" Blue " onclick="document.bgColor='#0000FF'">
```

This works but once the page is reloaded or refreshed, it goes back to the original colour, I want to know how I could implement cookies or sessions into this to make it stay.

Comment: what does this have to do with ASP ?  Everything here is clientside coding.  Please modify your posting if you are only seeking javascript for clientside behaviors.

Comment: @Dee: Its related to ASP since a possible solution would involve the server side script injecting the color into the generated HTML output and using the servers cookie or session management objects to track the color value.  It is true that the whole thing may possibly be solved client-side but if Rob knew that he might not need to ask this question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Javascripts native cookie handling is a pain. I strongly recommend using jquery and the excellent jquery cookie plugin. However, i believe your answer can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html